# jQuery .not() selector not working with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select all of the direct children of `body`, except for those that match a certain class.

Whether I use the `.not()` filter or the `:not()` selector, the element I'm trying to filter out is STILL part of the selection when I filter by class name. However, if I try to filter it out based on its id, it works fine.

Here are the selectors:

```
    console.log( $( 'body > *' ).not( '.fullscreen, script' ) );    // div.fullscreen is STILL part of the selection
    console.log( $( 'body > *' ).not( '#searchWindow, script' ) );  // div.fullscreen is gone, like I wanted
    console.log( $( 'body > *:not(.fullscreen, script)' ) );    // div.fullscreen is STILL part of the selection
    console.log( $( 'body > *:not(#searchWindow, script)' ) );  // div.fullscreen is gone, like I wanted
```

How come the class selector is without effect in this situation?

Here is a [jsfiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/tsyrak/yjnguz32/1/).

Comment: because you don't have `div.fullscreen`, it's `div.fulllscreen`

Comment: I can actually understand the down votes but what's the policy for asking stupid questions? Should I delete my question now that I realized my mistake?

Comment: We generally close them, but I'm not sure if the ones that have answers will go away on their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've spelt `fullscreen` wrong in your HTML. It has three `l`'s in it.

See here:

```
<div id="searchWindow" class="fulllscreen">
```

[Fixed Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yjnguz32/2/)

Comment: That's hilarious. Coding typos strike again. Thanks!

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert If I had 10 rep for every time I'd made a coding spelling mistake, I'd be beating Jon Skeet :). No worries, glad you got it sorted.